# Add single tap recogniser is not working in GMSMapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmsmapview

I am using GMSMapview and when I am implimenting single tap guesture on map then it is not working. how can I do this?

```
tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapDidTap:)];
tapRec.delegate = self;
tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[mapView2 addGestureRecognizer: tapRec];
```

and

```
 -(void)mapDidTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
[mapView2 removeGestureRecognizer:tapRec];
_filterView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: where you added the gesture , its called only one time correct, simple hide this `[mapView2 removeGestureRecognizer:tapRec];` and try once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am adding it on google map in view did load

Comment: no need of gesture, follow suit answer is fine , you can hide your view inside the delegate

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add tap gesture. GMSMapView provides its own method to detect the tap on particular latitude/longitude.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    //Coordinates where user has tapped
    print(coordinate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GMSMapView having delegate method. Integrate this method.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
```

Comment: good , no need of gesture just add the delegate and hide the view in here

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how can we see all the cordinates in map on a screen and should automatically zoomed out according to cordinates